# Adding personal experience to my cv

Tags: resume, work-experience, job-listing

During my unemployment days, when I was in urgent need of cash i resorted to collecting, buying selling of metal and plastic scrap, i also used to drive a taxi to earn my living, I am an MBA from a reputed institute.My question is can these things like taxi driver, scrap collector be added to the CV, as i believe its better to earn some how than to beg or be a sight of pity.

Comment: The days in which a person is unemployeed, what ever may be the reason, he is capable of work but cant find one.

Comment: Were your unemployment days before or after you were studying for your MBA? If they were after I can see including a brief mention of them just to keep from having gaps on your resume.

Answer (score 5):

*Can* they be added? Yes, of course they can. *Should* they be added? Probably not. What you did while you were between jobs has little if any bearing on how you perform a management role; I really don't care if you have some sort of moral objection to receiving handouts or not. Use the space on your CV for something which is directly relevant to the role you're applying for.

Comment: A job hunting session is all about marketing ones self, these sort of jobs also point out that a person can market him self to various catagories of work.Especially if one is applying for a marketing position.

Comment: Sure, but your question comes across more as a rant about what people do while unemployed than evidence of marketing skills.